# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, heroku

Help!  In my system, users search books and choose one and create one group for the book. But some users unintentionally created three groups for one book. Then I deleted the others. After that, I suddenly got the error below.

Now, users can't post any article.

☆heroku logs

```
2013-12-28T15:58:35.611503+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/group_messages/7/group_message_comments" for 119.72.194.92 at 2013-12-29 00:58:35 +0900
2013-12-28T15:58:35.614373+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by GroupMessageCommentsController#create as HTML
2013-12-28T15:58:35.614373+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SMyCZ8R97XIEMWQTzdYFMwcBRjtuoOgp7EDtpebyJRU=", "group_message_comment"=>{"member_id"=>"2", "group_message_id"=>"7", "group_id"=>"5", "content"=>"他人の地位を買収する、というより、その話題の彼が主宰するメンバーシップの中にお金を払って入ることができないという意味ですね。こちらはご参考です。http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buy+way+in\\r\\nSun Valley was always very reassuring, because unlike most elephant bumps, one could not buy one’s way\\r\\nin.ほかのこういうビッグネームの集まる類いのイベント（elepaht bump）の中には、お金さえ払えば参加できるものが主流なんでしょうね"}, "commit"=>"Comment", "group_message_id"=>"7"}
2013-12-28T15:58:35.624060+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-28T15:58:35.624060+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-28T15:58:35.624060+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-28T15:58:35.624060+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/group_message_comments_controller.rb:47:in `create'
2013-12-28T15:58:35.624060+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)
2013-12-28T15:58:35.624060+00:00 app[web.1]: : INSERT INTO "group_message_comments" ("content", "created_at", "group_id", "group_message_id", "member_id", "read", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"):
2013-12-28T15:58:35.621719+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms
```

☆group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :admin, :memo, :name

  has_many :group_in_members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :members, :through => :group_in_members
  has_many :group_messages, :dependent => :destroy


end
```

☆schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20131219064155) do

  create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "member_id"
    t.integer  "message_id"
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "contacts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name",       :null => false
    t.string   "email",      :null => false
    t.text     "content",    :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "friends", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "member_id",  :null => false
    t.integer  "friend_id",  :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "group_in_members", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "group_id",   :null => false
    t.integer  "member_id",  :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "group_message_comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "member_id",                           :null => false
    t.integer  "group_id",                            :null => false
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          :null => false
    t.integer  "group_message_id",                    :null => false
    t.boolean  "read",             :default => false
  end

  create_table "group_messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "member_id",                     :null => false
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",                    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                    :null => false
    t.integer  "group_id",                      :null => false
    t.integer  "page"
    t.integer  "line"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "username"
    t.boolean  "kaiketsu",   :default => false
  end

  create_table "groups", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
    t.string   "imageurl"
    t.string   "author"
    t.string   "publish"
    t.date     "published"
    t.integer  "page"
    t.string   "isbn"
    t.string   "asin"
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "detailurl",  :limit => 255
  end

  create_table "members", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "user"
    t.string   "pass"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "mail"
    t.text     "memo"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "pass_confirmation"
    t.string   "field"
    t.string   "place"
    t.string   "experience"
    t.string   "url"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "image"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "member_id"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "sessions", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "session_id", :null => false
    t.text     "data"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "sessions", ["session_id"], :name => "index_sessions_on_session_id"
  add_index "sessions", ["updated_at"], :name => "index_sessions_on_updated_at"

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "groups of the DB", but this seems like a straightforward case of trying to insert a value that is too large for the column definition of `varchar(255)`. I think you'll need to post more information if you want more help (e.g. specifics of what you deleted and why you think it's related to this error).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In my system, users search books and choose one and create one group for the book. But some users unintentionally created three groups for one book. Then I deleted the others. After that, I suddenly got this error.

Comment: I think it may be unrelated. How are you limiting or checking the length of comments in your controller before trying to post them?

Comment: Thank you very much. But the length of the comment was not that long. It worked before..

Comment: So the "comment" field in the params hash shown in your log is not actually the comment that was posted?

Comment: Sorry. It is. I cut "http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buy+way+in\\r\\nSun Valley was always very reassuring, because unlike most elephant bumps, one could not buy one’s way\\r\\nin." and then, I could post comments. I am not sure why the number of characters was limited. I didn't set the limitation on purpose.

Comment: String fields have a built-in limit of 255 characters in PG. You need to change the field to a text field if you want to capture more information. If you leave it as a string field, you need to validate in your model that the entry is under 255 characters, or it will continue throwing this error.